# Default configuration of SRIORestUploadBundle coupled with KnpGaufretteBundle doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony

I'd like use Symfony2 bundle SRIORestUploadBundle to handle the upload of a file through an API but after setting up the basic configuration, it still get the following error: `ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58:
The service "srio_rest_upload.storage.default" has a dependency on a non-existent service "gaufrette.uploads_filesyste".`

Comment: is it a typo, missing "m" `gaufrette.uploads_filesyste` ?

Comment: Exactly I appologies for it !

Comment: you´re welcome feel free to accept is as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a typo, missing `"m"` after `gaufrette.uploads_filesyste`

Answer (score 0):

I appologies for the fact I didn't do the configuration well (copy past doesn't necessary work with YAML). In fact the follwing config doesn't generate error:

```
knp_gaufrette:
```

adapters:
    local_uploads:
      local:
        directory: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads

filesystems:
    uploads:
      adapter: local_uploads

srio_rest_upload:
  storages:
    default:
      filesystem: gaufrette.uploads_filesystem